# Passing an array of strcture to a function in C

Tags: arrays, c, function, data-structures

I'm new to C language. Currently, i'm learning C data types and functions.

I'm trying to pass an array of structure in to another function.
My code is as below

```
 typedef struct {
   int indexNumber;
   float chemResult;
   float mathsResult;
   float phyResult;
 }stuResult;

 const int STU_NUM =10;

 void addStudent(stuResult stuData[]){
   ..........
 }
 
 int main(){
   stuResult stuData[STU_NUM];
   
   addStudent(stuData);
 }
```

This gives me an error "unknown type name stuResult in finction main"
I cannot figure out what I did wrong. Please help me.

I'm using the GNU GCC Compiler

Comment: Tip: Try and avoid global variables. Make sure to accept array/size pairs in functions like `addStudent` rather than *assuming* a global `const` applies.

Comment: Your code compiles fine if I replace the `.....` with anything reasonable.  You probably have a typo you didn't include with the code you posted.  That's why we ask you to include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, which you should ensure recreates the problem (often the excercise of doing this will show the answer), and then directly cut-and-paste it into your question (rather than retyping it)

Answer (score 1):

`typedef struct { ... } y` creates a *variable called `y`*. `typedef struct y { ... }` creates an alias `y` for `struct y`.

The corrected notation:

```c
typedef struct stuResult {
  int indexNumber;
  float chemResult;
  float mathsResult;
  float phyResult;
};
```